# LEFT OUTER JOIN not returning results when second table does not have values

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a SELECT statement that has a `LEFT OUTTER JOIN` that will cause a table to join to itself. The problem I am having is that when there are no results on the right side of the join the entire query retunes no results. I believe this is due to my `WHERE` clause but I tried to use `COALESCE` with `NULL` as the second value but that did not get any results.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT  tch1.WeekEndingDate AS WeekEndingDate, 
        tch1.TotalHoursWorked AS TotalHoursWorked, 
        e.ID AS ID, 
        e.FirstName AS FirstName, 
        e.PTORemaining AS PTORemaining, 
        so1.Name AS Name, 
        Extent5.Name AS Name1, 
        e.FirstName + N' ' + e.LastName AS C1, 
        tch2.WeekEndingDate AS WeekEndingDate1, 
        tch2.TotalHoursWorked AS TotalHoursWorked1
FROM dbo.TimeCardHeader AS tch1
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS e ON tch1.EmployeeID = e.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.StatusOption AS so1 ON tch1.CurrentStatusID = so1.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TimeCardHeader AS tch2 ON tch1.EmployeeID = tch2.EmployeeID
INNER JOIN dbo.StatusOption AS Extent5 ON tch2.CurrentStatusID = Extent5.ID
WHERE (tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND tch2.WeekEndingDate = '10/1/2016' AND e.ID = 80)
OR (tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND tch2.WeekEndingDate = '10/1/2016' AND e.ManagerID = 80);
```

For each, `WeekEndingDate` I tried to using `WeekEndingDate = COALESCE('9/24/2016', NULL)`

Is using `COALESCE` the correct thing to be doing and I am just using it wrong or is there another approach I should be using here so that even if there is no TimeCardHeader with a WeekEndingDate of `10/1/2016' I can get results.

Comment: COALESCE returns the first non-null value. What's the reason of having `null` as the last parameter of COALESCE?
If tch2 don't have any rows, then `AND tch2.column = 'whatever'` will be false. Have you tried changing it to something like `AND tch2.column IS NULL OR tch2.column = 'whatever'`?

Comment: Your `where` condition on the outer joined table turns the outer join into an inner join. You need to move that into the `join` condition (out off the `where`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Tried that, still getting 0 results back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, your inner join to StatusOption is based on CurrentStatusID from TimeCardHolder (tch2) which is a left join. If there is no row in tch2, then the inner join will end up with the results you are experiencing. Is there a way you could make StatusOption join (Extent5) a left join, and combine your where with the coalesce/isnull you already tried?

Comment: I updated to `LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TimeCardHeader AS tch2 ON tch1.EmployeeID = tch2.EmployeeID AND tch2.WeekEndingDate = '10/1/2016'
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.StatusOption AS so2 ON tch2.CurrentStatusID = so2.ID
WHERE tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND tch2.WeekEndingDate = COALESCE('10/1/2016', NULL) AND (e.ID = 80 OR e.ManagerID = 80);` but that is not returning results either.

Comment: As suggested by JNevill, it would be beneficial to go 'back to basics', and remove any where clauses and only join on keys (e.g remove week ending date check when joining to tch2). If that returns rows, then add in each condition 1 by 1 until you no longer get results. This should give you an insight on where your issue is

Comment: The issue is the date of 10/1/2016. I have done the "back to basics" where I removed all constraints. That gave me just about 100k rows. So started adding back some constrains and no matter what combination I have tried as soon as I add in the 10/1 date I either only get results for people that have a card for that date or no results at all. I need help figuring out the combo that lets me get results for everyone even if they don't have a card for 10/1 yet.

Comment: I have had a crack at trying to replicate the setup you have as a SQLFiddle, and dont seem to be able to get the same problem. Could you take a look at the following and see if there is anything I am missing from your original question? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/59383/5/0

Comment: It does not appear your missing anything, and when I take your SQL and run it against my DB it works. I am now comparing it to my SQL code to see where I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

`COALESCE()` isn't going to solve this. Right now your WHERE statement could be rewritten with no changes to:

```
 WHERE tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND tch2.WeekEndingDate = '10/1/2016' AND (e.ID = 80 OR e.ManagerID = 80)
```

Which is much simpler to understand. To bring in records where `tch2.WeekEndingDate` is either `10/1/2016` or NULL you could just add that in this simplified version:

```
 WHERE tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND (tch2.WeekEndingDate = '10/1/2016' OR tch2.WeekEndingDate IS NULL) AND (e.ID = 80 OR e.ManagerID = 80)
```

Which could also be written as:

```
 WHERE tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND tch2.WeekEndingDate IN ('10/1/2016',NULL) AND (e.ID = 80 OR e.ManagerID = 80)
```

Also, as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned in the comments, you could make your WHERE clause as:
          WHERE tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND (e.ID = 80 OR e.ManagerID = 80)

And change the LEFT OUTER JOIN's ON to:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TimeCardHeader AS tch2 ON tch1.EmployeeID = tch2.EmployeeID AND tch2.WeekEndingDate = '10/01/2016'
```

This will drop all records from tch2 BEFORE it's joined that don't have `WeekEndingDate` of `10/01/2016`

Comment: I have tried updating my where close to do `OR tch2.WeekEndingDate IS NULL` and that is still returning no results, I then tried to update the entire select to change the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as suggested but that still is returning no results.

Comment: The the issue has nothing to do with your LEFT OUTER JOIN. Perhaps, leaving the OUTER JOIN alone, remove all restrictions from your WHERE statement and see if you can find any records that match your requirements. My guess is you will find none. Perhaps the issue is one of your INNER JOINS, or you just don't have data that fits your requirements.

Comment: The problem is that there are no records that have a date of '10/1/2016' yet, but my understanding of the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is that because there is no records to return right side (10/1/2016) it would still return the left side but give me nulls for the right side. I need to craft the SQL so that when there is no record on the LEFT I get nulls.

Comment: Right, so you moved the restriction from the WHERE clause to the `ON` of your LEFT OUTER JOIN and still got no records. That means that your other restrictions in your `WHERE` clause are causing no records to return. At this point it has 100% nothing to do with your LEFT JOIN'd table. Your problem is elsewhere in your statement. Remove the remaining restrictions from your WHERE clause and see if you can figure out why you are getting nothing back. Or switch your INNER JOIN's to OUTER and see what comes through.

Comment: I can remove the `WHERE` clause and the only results I get back are those for people that have an entry for 10/1/2016 already. So even without the where clause I am not getting all the rows from the left side of the join

Comment: Good! you got records back... now check fields `tch1.weekendingdate`, `e.id` and `e.managerid` do they match your WHERE requirements.

Comment: Yes, I can find entries in the returned rows that have the correct Date and IDs. This is further backed up when I use `WHERE tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND (e.ID = 80 OR e.ManagerID = 80);` as my clause. This caluse gives me 80 rultes. 1 for every time card that user 80 has ever put in but he does not have a time card for 10/1/16 so there is no combo for that, as would be expected. I would also expect that if I put in a constraint for tch2 that made it return no results I would get an entry that contained the date for 9/24 on the left and nulls for 10/1 on the right.

Comment: I completely agree with your last statement. If you WHERE clause is `WHERE tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND (e.ID = 80 OR e.ManagerID = 80);` and you get 80 records back that have either null `tch2.weekendingdate` or a `tch2.weekendingdate` of `10/01/2016`, then either sticking `AND tch2.WeekEndingDate = '10/01/2016'` on your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` of the `tch2` table, or adding ` AND tch2.WeekEndingDate in ('10/01/2016', NULL)` to the WHERE should not change the number of results. Is `tch2.WeekEndingDate` a DATE type or string? Perhaps there is something there.

Comment: None of the 80 results have a record that has a null date or a date of 10/1 for `tch2.WeekEndingDate`. This is because there is no entry in `TimeCardHeader` with aa `WeekEndingDate` for 10/1/16. And yes, it is a DATETIME.

Answer (score 0):

Move the predicates relating to tch2 into the join clause:-

```
SELECT  tch1.WeekEndingDate AS WeekEndingDate, 
        tch1.TotalHoursWorked AS TotalHoursWorked, 
        e.ID AS ID, 
        e.FirstName AS FirstName, 
        e.PTORemaining AS PTORemaining, 
        so1.Name AS Name, 
        Extent5.Name AS Name1, 
        e.FirstName + N' ' + e.LastName AS C1, 
        tch2.WeekEndingDate AS WeekEndingDate1, 
        tch2.TotalHoursWorked AS TotalHoursWorked1
FROM dbo.TimeCardHeader AS tch1
INNER JOIN dbo.Employee AS e ON tch1.EmployeeID = e.ID
INNER JOIN dbo.StatusOption AS so1 ON tch1.CurrentStatusID = so1.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.TimeCardHeader AS tch2 ON tch1.EmployeeID = tch2.EmployeeID 

    AND tch2.WeekEndingDate = '10/1/2016'

INNER JOIN dbo.StatusOption AS Extent5 ON tch2.CurrentStatusID = Extent5.ID
WHERE (tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016'  AND e.ID = 80)
OR (tch1.WeekEndingDate = '9/24/2016' AND e.ManagerID = 80);
```

If you have them in the where clause you are filtering out the joined rows altogether.

Comment: I have tried updating it as suggested, adding the `AND` clause to the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but I am still getting no results.